# Getting error: EntityMetadataWrapperException: Unknown data property group_access

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

Getting below error when changing Target state field value from Draft to Approved of a content.

> EntityMetadataWrapperException: Unknown data property group_access. in EntityStructureWrapper->getPropertyInfo() (line 354 of /sites/all/modules/entity/includes/entity.wrapper.inc).

I have already tried solutions mentioned at below requests & they are not working for me.

- https://www.drupal.org/project/entity/issues/2819665
- https://www.drupal.org/node/1819790

Comment: Where is your code ? If I'm not wrong the `group_access` field is brought by og module, are you (still) using it ?

Comment: Yes, the system is using that module.